How do I call a Function in window2 from the page I opened it from window2?
I and trying to open a window with the window.open code,
var myWindow = window.open(url , name, details);
and then I want to execute a function in that window after it loads.
var myWindow = window.open(url , name, details);
myWindow.doSomething();

The Idea is to have it both triggered by a button, HTML based.
I have just been rewriting it in different ways, and thus far nothing seems to work. Any input would be appreciated.

You could try using a combination of postMessage() and an event listener inside the new window, as explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

if it's same origin, easy, wait for it to load first of course. If the window is not same origin, you'll have to use postMessage as per previous comment

In your situation, that is because the limitation of the browser's Same Origin policy,
it is not realistic to attempt to manipulate the method in window B created by window A through the script in window A.
so .doSomething() must be defined in the context of the window that is being opened, and you can use postMessageAPI, window A can send messages to window B, which receives these messages by listening to message events and performs corresponding operations based on the message content.
